# What does the import ide do in python 2.3?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some library in python 2.3.x which I want to port to 2.7.x, however I have a library called **ide** which I cannot find. Is this a python 2.3 standard library and if it is how can I use/override it in python 2.7.x?

Code snippet:

```
import ide;
import ghs_misc;
from ghs_util import *;
import sys;
import re;

def GHS_GetDebuggerService(serviceName, workingDir, pluginId):
    """ Get MULTI debugger service. """
    ret = ide.open(serviceName, workingDir, pluginId);
    if (ret == None):
    print("Cannot launch Debugger service." );
    else:
    ret.SetOutputMask(0xff);
    return ret;
```

I get the following error running in python 2.7.x:

```
import ide
ImportError: No module named ide
```

Comment: `ide` is not a standard library module, as you could have found out by looking at `https://docs.python.org/2/py-modindex.html#cap-i`. You'll have to find out from the author/maintainer of this code where he got it. By the way, his Python is written with an atrocious C accent. Don't imitate it.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer and for your feedback as well.